# Listening to PropertyChanged event on main thread, for changes done in background threads

Tags: ios, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.ios, realm

Not sure if this is possible, but I going through the documentation it gave me the impression that realm is built around this sort of thing. I'm trying to listen for changes done to the realm object which are carried out in a background thread.

The code listed below will add an Post object to the realm, read the object and listen to it's property changed event. When I update that object directly, the event is raised. But when I read the object on another thread and update it, I would expect the object on the main thread to get the update, but this is not the case. Am I missing something ?

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
string newPostID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

realm.Write(() => {
var newPost = realm.CreateObject<Post>();
    newPost.ID = newPostID;
    newPost.Count = 0;
});

var post = realm.All<Post>().Where(item => item.ID == newPostID).FirstOrDefault();
post.PropertyChanged += (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    // Changed
};

Realm.GetInstance().Write(() =>
{
    var threadPost = Realm.GetInstance().All<Post>().Where(item => item.ID == newPostID).FirstOrDefault();

    threadPost.Count++;
    // This will trigger the PropertyChanged event
});

Task.Run(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        Realm.GetInstance().Write(() =>
        {
            var threadPost = Realm.GetInstance().All<Post>().Where(item => item.ID == newPostID).FirstOrDefault();

            threadPost.Count++;
            // This will not trigger the PropertyChanged event on the main thread
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This was recently implemented in the .NET SDK](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/pull/909), and so your code should work as you expect it to with the next release of Realm Xamarin.

Comment: Any idea when is this planned to be released ?

Comment: We generally avoid giving specific dates, as those are always subject to change, and instead prefer to use [soon™](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Soon). That being said, we are optimistic about shipping a new version before the holidays. If you feel you can't wait and want it now, you can always build from [source](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/#building-realm).

Comment: I understand what you mean

I was actually looking for a beta channel on nuget, didn't know I could use the sources to get not yet released code. Will give it a go, Thanks for the replies

Comment: We've now released [Realm 0.81.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/releases/tag/0.81.0) which includes support for that.